# error LNK2005: "int __cdecl number(void)" (?number@@YAHXZ) already defined in functions.obj

Tags: c++, include

I think I am having a similar problem to [LNK2005, LNK1169 errors, "int __cdecl g(void)" (?g@@YAHXZ) already defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256046/lnk2005-lnk1169-errors-int-cdecl-gvoid-gyahxz-already-defined) but I cannot find the issue.

I am working with Visual Basic and I am having the following files

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    number();
    return 0;
}
```

I had a `functions.cpp` but after reading the question I linked before I renamed it for **functions.h**

```
int number(){
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

Now it is displaying  `error LNK2005: "int __cdecl number(void)" (?number@@YAHXZ) already defined in functions.obj`

Is there anything wrong with the function `number()` in `functions.h`?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, including `functions.h` somewhere else as well, in your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You are having linking issues.

Your immediate issue is that the `functions.obj` contains code that is being linked in. Then you redefine `number()` in `main.cpp` so they collide. Go ahead and clean the project (which should delete `functions.obj`, and you should be able to compile.  I, however, recommend doing it this way.

**functions.hpp** (or functions.h)

```
int number();
```

**functions.cpp**

```
int number(){
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    number();
    return 0;
}
```

When you compile, your program will create 2 objects with compiled code `functions.obj`, and `main.obj`.  Since you use `number` in the main file, the compiler looks for the implementation of that function.  Since the implementation of that function is in the `functions.obj` object, then you need to link that in.

**If you are going to use** `number()` **across several C++ files, then you should always separate the code out into its own file and implementation.**

Comment: If I try to fix / add the .cpp file in my old project is doesn't work, but if I do a new one it does. Why is that? Is there anything related with what you meant by cleaning? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1475038/2565304

Comment: Well, lots of IDE's provide a "Clean" function of sorts, which deletes any unnecessary files.  Go and look for the `functions.obj` file and delete it!

Answer (score 2):

functions.h should only declare the functio, as in

```
int number();
```

then functions.cpp should contain the function definition

```
int number(){
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

Of course functions.cpp needs to be compiled (add it to the project).

The problem here is that you are including functions.h in multiple files. The issue could be avoided also by simply declaring the function `static` as in

```
static int number(){
    int i = 1;
    return i;
}
```

However, since it seems you are just learning, I would suggest you to study the basics of compiling c++ code.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the modules you link in there is a function with the name `number()`. You define you own implementation so the linker does not know which one to use.

Either rename your function or use namespaces.